# Firefox always sends me to localized domains

Tags: firefox

I'm using Firefox. Whenever I go to Hotmail, Yahoo, Google, etc. I get myself thrown to hotmail.mx, yahoo.mx, google.mx and so on.

This of course is not what I want, and yeah, the same page gives me the option of "cancelling" the redirect – just telling it not to and marking the option of not asking me again.

Firefox doesn't save my pick though. I get redirected every single time because apparently Firefox isn't saving my preferences as it does anywhere else in any other equip, yet somehow seems my computer has a lock in this thing.

Any ideas how can I fix it?

Comment: Is this only in Firefox, or every other browser on this computer?

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing it's not really a Firefox problem. Various websites automatically redirect you to country-specific pages by geolocating your IP address. For example, here's Google's page on the topic, including some possible workarounds:

http://support.google.com/websearch/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=873

Answer (score 0):

[Change the primary language of Firefox to English](http://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/settings-fonts-languages-pop-ups-javascript?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=Options+window+-+Content+panel#w_languages), then tell us if you keep getting redirects.

Answer (score 0):

For google you need to go here
http://www.google.com/ncr
so it will stay on google.com

for other services (yahoo, hotmail...) I don't know